# How i can call a function from external javascript file in another external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have 2 external javaScript files. I want to call a `function` of first file into second file.
any body can help me?
How i can call a  function from external javascript file in another  external javascript file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 2):

`JS` *prints* the values on DOM, so once the page has been rendered on the browser, it is all treated as *one large document*. This means, after parsing, you can call any function from any JS file *ONLY IF* that function has been loaded on DOM *before* your calling function!

That explained, assuming you have 2 files `js1.js` and `js2.js`,having `fn1()` in js1 and `fn2()` in js2

So if you have to call `fn1()` in `js1.js`, load it before `js2.js`, once loaded simply make a call to `fn1()` from `js2.js` and it would work!!

**js1.js**

```
function fn1(){
 // some code
}
```

**js2.js**

```
function fn2(){
 fn1(); //function call to another file.
}
```

**Just ensure the order of loading :**

```
<script src="js1.js" type="script/javascript"> <!-- Load the main program JS first -->
<script src="js2.js" type="script/javascript"> <!--Load the calling program JS after it -->
```

**One additional way of doing it**

```
<script src="js1.js" type="script/javascript"> //Load the main program JS first
<script language="javascript">
   fn1(); //call the function directly from the HTML embedded JS :)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

import both js file into a single html page, and then any function you want to call from any where you want

html

```
<html>
//
<script type="text/javascript" src="1st.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="2nd.js"></script>
//
</html>
```

1st.js

```
function js1(){
//...
}
```

2nd.js

```
function js2(){
js1();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- You have to make sure that script from which you are calling your
  function is downloaded after the script in which you have your
  function;
- And, of course, that the place from where you are calling you function has scope access to the function you call.