# Call a function in an external .js file from another .js file

Tags: javascript, file, function, reference, external

I have two .js files:

Card_API.js
script.js

I want to be able to call functions in Card_API.js from script.js.

My references in the HTML file look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Card_API.js"><\script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"><\script>
```

in the Card_API.js file, I have a function:

```
function sortCardsByMana(array, reverse){
    // Do Stuff
}
```

I want to be able to call the above function in the script.js file, but when I try it like this:

```
sortCardsByMana(cards, false);
```

...it gives an error saying that the function is not defined.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if I it's possible?

Comment: Make sure that you are including `Card_API.js` with a script tag before `script.js`. Otherwise, `script.js` would not be able to call those functions because they wouldn't exist at the time that the file is loaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546142/how-i-can-call-a-function-from-external-javascript-file-in-another-external-java24546171#24546171

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine—just make sure that the `.js` file making the call is included in the webpage second.

(When the browser is looking through `script.js` and sees `sortCardsByMana(cards, false);`, it has no idea what you're talking about—yet!)

Comment: That's what I've done but it's refusing to recognize the function. Do I need to be hosting the files on a server or does it work locally too?

Answer (score 1):

include `Card_API.js` before `script.js` .